# Einstein Engagement Frequency - what do the resulting data extensions look like and are they accessible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, einstein

I've been reading the documentation and watching some demos on the Einstein Engagement Frequency in Marketing Cloud (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_eef_create_de.htm&type=5)

The feature allows you to create data extensions of your oversaturated and undersaturated subscribers.

However, I can't find any specific info about these resulting data extensions. Specifically, I would like to know:

- What fields are in the data extensions?
- Are they accessible via the UI once created?
- Can they be used in queries?
- Can they be used as a send audience and/or suppression audience (I'm pretty sure they can but just want to double check)?

Has anyone used the feature and can confirm answers to the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DE can be located in the root directory once the applications has been provisioned to the account and both have a sendable relationship on SubscriberID = SubscriberID. Like any DE they can be used in a query. I attached a screen shot below, both DE's have the same fields

[image: Fields]

Comment: Thanks EazyE. Is SubscriberID the same as what's usually called SubscriberKey? Also, curious about the LongNumber field type for SubscriberID - what is that? We use the Salesforce ContactID for our subscriberkey. Do you do the same?

Comment: Subscriberid is not Subscriberkey. SubscriberID(BIG INT) is the uniqueid defined by the system for the entire instance, while subscriberkey(nvarchar) is the uniqueid defined by the customer for the Account.  If you feel they need to visualize subscriberkey you would need to join this DE on the _subscribers dataview which has both id & key

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. A follow up: let's say I use the Oversaturated DE as a exclusion audience in a send - it only has SubscriberID and my send audience DE would only have SubscriberKey - how does it ensure the correct subscribers are excluded?

Comment: Correct because they both have the correct sendable relationship

Comment: Ok thanks. Salesforce sure do like to make things confusing! If they can make the link between SubscriberID and SubscriberKey, why don't they just put SubscriberKey in the DE as well...

Comment: @EazyE this has changed recently right? In late 2020 I believe. Can you still create data extensions? I am not seeing the option. Also, do you know if Engagement Frequency works across business units?